# Difference in the commit chosen between Plutus Pioneers lecture and given documents

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

When building plutus-apps locally I encountered a difference between the [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13112LHG9vVvNUs40oZSqZ-DF6_yFiT_SJZ2NaEmjMM4/edit#) that was shared a few days ago and the [first lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPaDp4R9X7o&t=300s) of Plutus Pioneers.

The document says the following:

```
git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a
```

In the first lecture of plutus pioneers we have the following:

```
git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a
```

Should I build plutus-apps again with the commit version specified on the video or the version described in the documents is fine?

Comment: As I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, I'll post my comments here. In your question you have used the same commit number from both sources (document and video). I assume that's a typo. The commit listed in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPaDp4R9X7o&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2nLM4fAck2JS6KhFQlXq2N&index=3 (time 4:24) is 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a and that matches what's in plutus-pioneer-program/cabal-project. What was the commit in the document (I can't determine which source you used)?

Comment: @SteveMason Welcome aboard!  Please follow the guidelines in the help center and accept the limitations that your account has.  I know it is frustrating but they are there for the benefit of the community and the quality of the site.  We all benefit in the long run.

Comment: @SteveMason Here's how to build up your reputation so that you can comment: [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Each week there will be a new id/tag for the git checkout, as Plutus is under constant development. Use the one from the lecture this week, and then next week use the one from next week's lecture.

Here's a video which helps explain commits and checking out. I'm new to this stuff as well so it helped me understand a bit better.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7y_htm0sw-I

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

I used `git checkout 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd` and it worked. It's a bit more recent.

Answer (score 0):

The commit in the lecture, which is the one in the cabal file of the first week code works fine and I would recommend using that to be in line with the lecturer.